# How to get date of a weekday given the week and year

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I would like to find the date when given the week and the year.
For example

```
         year = 2021;
         week = 2;
         day = Thursday;
```

I would like to return 01-07-2021

For this, I am first trying to get the first date of week 2 in 2021. Add 4 to the day to get the date.

```
   const startDateOfWeek2 = ??
```

I believe if I can get the `startDate` then I can calculate for any weekday in that week. Is there a way I can use `moment` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `moment` framework, you can get the day based on `weeknumber` and `year` using `week()` and `year()` function as follows.

```js
const year = 2021;
const weekNumber = 2;

const weekDay = moment().year(year).week(weekNumber).day("Wednesday");
console.log(weekDay.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: W - Thank you, I was trying something similar . However, the day is always off by 1 .For example, it returns 01-08-2020(Friday). I guess it has something to do with counting from 0-6 Vs 1-7 for the days? I tried this for week 3 as well and get 01-15-2020,instead of 01-14-2020. Any idea why?

Comment: I have updated my answer. It is needed to put from year->day (keeping the sequence.) If use `day()` and then use `week()`, the `day()` function will be retained.

Comment: Thank you! I dont understand how the sequence played in .I had used  day -> week -> year, thinking start with the most smallest unit. Is there a reason year->week->day worked?

Comment: When using `week()`, the lower func `day()` will be retained. So instead of `day -> week -> year`, use `year->week->day`. Think, decide year first and then week and then day. From top to down.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation. I spent a lot of time without thinking about the sequence.